# how do I check the file size of a video in flutter before uploading

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I want to upload a video file to my cloud storage but I want to check the size of the video file before I upload. how to achieve this

Comment: Please mark this as accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66473018/8164116

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you have the path of the file, you can use `dart:io`

```
var file = File('the_path_to_the_video.mp4');
```

You an either use:

```
print(file.lengthSync());
```

or

```
print (await file.length());
```

---

Note: The size returned is in `bytes`.

Comment: when I tried I got this:
hashcode:844733706
Type (FileSystemException)
"Cannot retrieve length of file"
path:"File: '/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20181028-WA0018.mp4'"

Comment: Can you please try `file.resolveSymbolicLinksSync().lengthSync()`

Comment: [dart] The method 'lengthSync' isn't defined for the class 'String'.

Comment: Ok, then `File(file.resolveSymbolicLinksSync()).lengthSync()`

Comment: it will return the size in bytes?

Comment: Yes, the length is in bytes.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zzpmaster/ec51afdbbfa5b2bf6ced13374ff891d9 combine it with this. Perfect !

Comment: If you are using the latest ImagePicker Which Returns PickedFile instead of File.
```formatBytes(await File(image.path).lengthSync(), 2)
```

Answer (score 53):

// **defined the function**

```
getFileSize(String filepath, int decimals) async {
    var file = File(filepath);
    int bytes = await file.length();
    if (bytes <= 0) return "0 B";
    const suffixes = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB"];
    var i = (log(bytes) / log(1024)).floor();
    return ((bytes / pow(1024, i)).toStringAsFixed(decimals)) + ' ' + suffixes[i];  
}
```

// **how to call the function**

```
print(getFileSize('file-path-will-be-here', 1));
```

// **output will be as string like:**

```
97.5 KB
```

This worked for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks a lot for asking question.

Comment: Thank you Kamlesh. This is almost matching with the real size of the file. In the console is saying 2.72 MB and in filesystem is showing 2.9 MB.

Comment: @FlorentinLupascu I am not sure but this may be different due to 1 MB = 1000 KB instead of 1024 KB.

Comment: This is a really nice function!!  +1

Comment: @Kamlesh can we use this with a folder?

Comment: @LearnToday dear, I did not check it with a folder yet, checked only for file only. Thanks.

Comment: What is the use of int decimals @Kamlesh

Comment: @OttomanCoder `decimals` param is used to set number of precision after decimal. eg. If you want to get 2 precision after integer decimal value in result then you can just pass param `2` in `getFileSize('file-path-will-be-here', 2);` function which will result you `97.53 KB`. I hope, now you are clear about `int decimals`. Thanks for sharing your query :)

Comment: Just to point it out, since it is `1024` here, they should be `KiB` `MiB` etc

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Kindly remove your comment from this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

This is work for me.

```
final file = File('pickedVid.mp4');            
int sizeInBytes = file.lengthSync();
double sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
if (sizeInMb > 10){
    // This file is Longer the
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the latest ImagePicker with **xFile** type then,

```
 final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  print(File(photo.path).lengthSync());
```

**will return the file size in bytes.**

Answer (score 2):

```dart
import 'dart:io';

//Here's the method to get file size:

double getFileSize(File file){      
    int sizeInBytes = file.lengthSync();
    double sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
    return sizeInMb;
}

//Alternatively for extension:

extension FileUtils on File {
    get size {
        int sizeInBytes = this.lengthSync();
        double sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
        return sizeInMb;
    }
}
```