# Trying to retrieve file length in flutter but I get the following exception -" FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access the length of the file using the following code:-

```
File file = File('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mynewapp/files/Pictures/IMG_20200322_202358.jpg');
final length = await file.length();
```

and I get the following exception-

> FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mynewapp/files/Pictures/IMG_20200322_202358.jpg'

I followed the suggestions from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036328/how-do-i-check-the-file-size-of-a-video-in-flutter-before-uploading) and tried without the await:-

`final length = file.lengthSync();`

also

`final length = File(file.resolveSymbolicLinksSync()).lengthSync()`

but I end up getting the same exception.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using a function that will provide you with the file size as a neat formatted string.

Imports:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
```

Output:

```
File image = new File('image.png');
print(getFilesizeString(bytes: image.lengthSync()}); // Output: 17kb, 30mb, 7gb
```

Function:

```
// Format File Size
static String getFileSizeString({@required int bytes, int decimals = 0}) {
  const suffixes = ["b", "kb", "mb", "gb", "tb"];
  var i = (log(bytes) / log(1024)).floor();
  return ((bytes / pow(1024, i)).toStringAsFixed(decimals)) + suffixes[i];
}
```

If you want to just get a length without caring about the unit so you do care about the size condintionaly You can get the file size by this code :

```
final bytes = image.readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes; 
final kb = bytes / 1024; 
final mb = kb / 1024;
```

Answer (score -1):

do you have a Permission to read this file ? try to check that then use the lengthSync to get the value directly and not a future of the Value
i tryed that and it is work after i add the storge Permission

```
File f = new File('your path');
s = f.lengthSync()
print(s);
```

Comment: Yes, I have the permission to read this file and cross checked by trying to print the file. After checking this I also tried file.lengthSync() and end up with the same exception.