# How to get the size of An asset image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am picking a image from gallery i need the size of the image in bytes how can i get that?

I try this but it is giving wrong size i picked up 2 images of 127 kb each but this print 308

```
List<Asset> assets = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(maxImages: count, enableCamera: showCamera);
    for (int i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
      await assets[i].getByteData().then((value) {
        print("${value.lengthInBytes/1000}");
      });
    }
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040464/11377302) might help you.